# ASP.Net Core 5 MVC - Default image from wwwroot folder if no image is selected on a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

How does one set a default image in a cshtml form if no image is selected?
I have tried to do an "...If... ...Else..." statement in the controller, but it doesn't seem to be working.
Here is the current code snippet I have:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PetReg petReg, List<IFormFile> Pet1ChipImage, byte[] bytes)
        {
            foreach (var item in Pet1ChipImage)
            {
                if (item.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
                        petReg.Pet1ChipImage = stream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string contenttype = string.Empty;
                    string filename = string.Empty;
                    filename = "no-image.png";
                    contenttype = "image/png";
                    Image defaultImage = Image.FromFile(MyServer.MapPath("~/Images/Default.png"));

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        await item.CopyToAsync(ms);
                        bytes = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: if you image is uploaded how do you expect the foreach loop to run?

Comment: Copy the else block outside the loop and check if list.Count == 0 then upload default image

Comment: It looks like this method is supposed to save a file `byte[]` to a database. Are you asking about how to *display* a default image if no image was saved?

Comment: In my opinion, this requirement may not be possible, `input` can't manually set the default file, so we can't pass the default file directly from the frontend to the backend. If the `input` is null, the `List<IFormFile>` will decrease by one count, and it is also impossible to locate how many `input` tags are null and where they are located.